# Kur training speech.yml while tensorflow not compling and libmagic is not available

Tags: deep-learning, speech-recognition

I am new to kur and just trying it out.

with `kur -v train speech.yml`, it runs fine but with some annoying messages: 1. The tensorflow is not compiling SSE instructions; 2. system library 'libmagic' can't be found.

Should I worry about these? should I do something about these?

Thanks a lot! @AdamSypniewski where is the best place to ask questions about kur?

> W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   [INFO 2017-02-26 14:33:20,651 kur.backend.keras_backend:654] Waiting for model to finish compiling...
>   [WARNING 2017-02-26 14:33:20,657 kur.utils.audiotools:98] Python package "magic" could not be loaded, possibly because system library "libmagic" could not be found. We are falling back on our own heuristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "TensorFlow library wasn't compiled" warning is just a warning (c.f., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463698/2200851)). Every thing will still work fine, but it is possible that you'll get a boost in performance if you compile/install TensorFlow from source, rather than from pip/conda. That's all.

The "libmagic" warning can (probably) be ignored as well. "libmagic" is the name of a library which uses [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) to determine the file type of an arbitrary file. Current versions of macOS don't have it installed by default, so Kur falls back onto its own file-format heuristic. If you aren't seeing errors and if your model output seems reasonable, you're probably fine. If you want to be super-careful, you can use a macOS package manager to install it; for example, using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), the command is `brew install libmagic`.

And since you asked, the best place to ask questions about Kur is on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/deepgram-kur/Lobby).