# How to compile Tensor Flow with SSE and AVX instructions on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, msbuild, tensorflow

With the latest version of Tensor Flow now on windows, I am trying to get everything working as efficiently as possible. However, even when compiling from source, I still can't seem to figure out how to enable the SSE and AVX instructions.

The default process:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.12/tensorflow/contrib/cmake
has no mention of how to do this.

The only reference I have found has been using Google's Bazel:
[How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions)

Does anyone know of an easy way to turn on these advanced instructions using MSBuild? I hear they give at least a 3X speed up.

To help those looking for a similar solution, this is the warning I am currently getting looks like this:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.12/tensorflow/contrib/cmake

I am using Windows 10 Professional on a 64 bit platform, Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, Anaconda Python 3.6 with cmake version 3.6.3 (later versions don't work for Tensor Flow)

Comment: side note, they give "at most" 3x speed-up. You'll see this speed-up if your computation is mostly huge matrix multiplies

Answer (score 6):

Well, I tried to fix that, but I am not sure if it really worked.

In `CMakeLists.txt` you will find the following statements:

```
if (tensorflow_OPTIMIZE_FOR_NATIVE_ARCH)
  include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
  CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-march=native" COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED)
```

On MSVC platform, the test failes because MSVC doesn't support `-march=native` flag. I modified the statements like below:

```
if (tensorflow_OPTIMIZE_FOR_NATIVE_ARCH)
  include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
  CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-march=native" COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED)
  if (COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native")
  else()
    CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("/arch:AVX" COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_AVX_SUPPORTED)
    if(COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_AVX_SUPPORTED)
      set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /arch:AVX")
    endif()
  endif()
endif()
```

By doing this, cmake would check if `/arch:AVX` is available and use it. Accordinf to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620901.aspx), SSE2 support is enabled by default for x86 compiling but not available for x64 compiling. For x64 compiling you can choose to use AVX or AVX2. I used AVX above because my CPU only supports AVX, youcan try AVX2 if you have a compatible CPU.

By compiling use the above `CMakeLists.txt`, the compiling preocedure was much slower than official release, and warning about 'AVX/AVX2' disappeared, but warning about SSE/SSE2/3/4.1/4.2 still exists. I think these warnings can be ignored because there's no SSE support for x64 MSBuild.

I am testing the new pip package now. It maybe faster than before, but I don't want to write a new benchmark ...

Any one who is interested in this, please test if the new package is really faster.

I did all these on the lasted git master branch, 2017-3-12. The pip package name shows that it was tensorflow 1.0.1

Comment: Compiling with the instructions from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/v1.1.0/tensorflow/contrib/cmake) with these adaptions works, but I see no speed-up, if building and running the GPU version. Note that I've also tried AVX2 the very same way, but as @TLJ mentioned, it is currently broken.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would have to add `/arch:avx2` to compiler flags.
One way to do it is to modify your `CMakeCache.txt` in your build folder. Looking for a line `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING` and modify it to

> ```
> CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /arch:AVX2 /fp:fast
> ```

However, according to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7966) on github. `/arch:avx2` is broken at the moment (at HEAD).

Comment: Tried your suggestion of editing the CMakeCache.txt file in the build folder... after uninstalling/reinstalling the new build, no luck :(. Is there not a cmake option I can pass in to do the same thing?

Comment: From `CMakeLists.txt`, the flag `tensorflow_OPTIMIZE_FOR_NATIVE_ARCH` (default to On) supposes to set `-march=native` automatically for everyone opt-in compiling the code. This should do the trick when using gcc. I'm not sure if it does the same on VC.

Comment: @Aerophilic I am studying about this too. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx), SSE2 support is enabled by default.

Comment: @Aerophilic Well, SSE/SSE2 are for x86 only, and for x64 you shall use [AVX/AVX2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620901.aspx). For my CPU, only AVX is supported. I am tring to compile with `/arch:AVX` option, and I'll post it here if there is any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow make a mistake on flag "tensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS".

It is a Flag, not a Boolean.

[Before Fix Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cizF7.png)

[After Fix Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9vEn.png)

---

### How to Fix it

"Tensorflow-github/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/CMakeLists.txt" Line 34,there is:

```
option(tensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS "Enables CPU SIMD instructions")
```

Replace it wtih

```
set(tensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS "/arch:AVX" CACHE STRING "Enables CPU SIMD instructions" )
```

Then, clear the cmake cache ([location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eSnf.png)), and reconfigure.

You will find tensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS is a Flag with Input area instead of checkbox.

---

### tensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS

"/arch:AVX" or "/arch:AVX2" is available