# Compiling Tensorflow with CMake on Windows fails with file version_info.cc not found

Tags: python, windows, build, tensorflow, cmake

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603407/how-to-compile-tensor-flow-with-sse-and-and-avx-instructions-on-windows/42755665#42755665) question and related to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions) questions, I would like to build Tensorflow on Windows from sources to enable the CPU optimizations that are [deactivated by design to support as many machines as possible](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7257#issuecomment-277768292). From the official documentation that suggests that [Bazel is not supported on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), I conclude that the CMake build is the way to go.

I found the CMake instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/v1.1.0/tensorflow/contrib/cmake), where I assumed that by checking out Tag v1.1.0, I could be able to build it. But after following the instructions, I get the following error-message:

```
Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Alex\Repositories\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Alex\Repositories\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
"C:\Users\Alex\Repositories\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\pywrap_tensorflow_internal_static.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
"C:\Users\Alex\Repositories\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_cpu.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
"C:\Users\Alex\Repositories\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (6) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Users\Alex\Repositories\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\util\version_info.cc': No such file or directory [C:\Users\Alex\Repositories\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_framework.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

which claims that version_info.cc could not be found. What is that file, how is it generated and why is it missing? Is there a way, how I can create it to complete my build or am I missing some configuration that was not mentioned in the document?

Comment: Please, move section under "Update" to the **answer post** (*self-answering* is allowed on Stack Overflow). We tend to not mix problems and solutions in question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a [known bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/9660/files) that is already fixed on master branch, but still exists in older versions. Manually patching the files or using master branch solves this issue.