# Tensorflow compilation error with latest tensorflow source on MacOS

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build the tensorflow source on my Mac OSx Yosemite (10.10.5). After I run this command

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get this error

C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core:candidate_sampling_ops_op_lib' failed: cc_wrapper.sh failed: **error** executing command external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -fcolor-diagnostics -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG ... (remaining 95 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
tensorflow/core/ops/candidate_sampling_ops.cc:392:7: **error**: return type 'tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
      return Status::OK();
      ^
tensorflow/core/ops/candidate_sampling_ops.cc:376:17: error: no viable conversion from 'tensorflow::(lambda at tensorflow/core/ops/candidate_sampling_ops.cc:376:17)' to 'tensorflow::Status (*)(shape_inference::InferenceContext *)'
    .SetShapeFn([](InferenceContext* c) {

What may I be doing wrong ?

Comment: already tried to delete and reinstall tensorflow? if so: what version are you using?

Comment: Yes. I re-downloaded again. I followed the instructions https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

and  did (which means latest version of the the tensorflow)

git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

(outdated but still relevant for this version of TF)
The latest version of tensorflow is NOT compileable/working for mac os x.

Here is my script to get tensorflow working on mac-osx sierra tensorflow 1.0 on mac-osx sierra i7 no gpu. I'm still working on getting SSE and such to compile correctly and a later version of tensorflow - but whatever. Tensorflow is not friently with macs - but DL4J is!

UPDATE:
You shouldn't need to update from Yosemite. I was able to get r1.3 to compile with SSE and AVX! So the 'latest release' at time of writing has known issues - r1.3 is the latest stable build. I've included the script to do a proper build below, but also including http://www.josephmiguel.com/building-tensorflow-1-3-from-source-on-mac-osx-sierra-macbook-pro-i7-with-sse-and-avx/ for all the details on the matter.

```
one time install

install anaconda3 pkg # manually download this and install the package
conda update conda
conda create -n dl python=3.6 anaconda
source activate dl

cd /
brew install bazel
pip install six numpy wheel
pip install –upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/protobuf-3.1.0-cp35-none-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl

sudo -i
cd /
rm -rf tensorflow # if rerunning the script
cd /
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

 
Step 1

cd /tensorflow
git checkout r1.3 -f
cd /
chmod -R 777 tensorflow
cd /tensorflow
./configure # accept all default settings

 
Step 2

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions
bazel build –config=opt –copt=-mavx –copt=-mavx2 –copt=-mfma //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

 
Step 3

bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl

 
Step 4

cd ~
ipython

 
Step 5

import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant(‘Hello, TensorFlow!’)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))

 
Step 6

pip uninstall /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl
```