# How to use a self-compiled tensorflow with support for SSE4.2 and AVX instruction in a conda environment?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conda

The tensorflow webpage explains clearly how to self-compile tensorflow. [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions) explains how this can be done with SSE4.2 and AVX instruction support. But I cannot find instructions on how to do this within an isolated conda environment.

So my question is: How do I do this within an isolated conda environment so that it is available for keras?

Side question: how much speedup can I expect from including these instruction sets?

Update: I figured out the answer to this question and posted the answer here:
[How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions/43107977#43107977)

Comment: Can't you just use pip inside your conda env?

Comment: You are correct. After compiling tensorflow, I just need do do the pip install of the wheel within a conda environment.