# Import Warnings in Tensorflow

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow

I get these warnings while importing tensorflow.

System : Windows 10 64 bit

Python : 3.5.2

Tensorflow-CPU: 1.1.0 Nightly build

```
2017-04-04 16:59:56.185045: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-04 16:59:56.185185: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-04 16:59:56.186551: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-04 16:59:56.187141: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-04 16:59:56.187629: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-04 16:59:56.188138: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

Although these are not a problem while running it in python, but the problem arises when I am calling the python script from MATLAB, I have a friend who has done same thing with Theano and he told me you have to reomve all the errors and warnings in order for it to work on MATLAB. I have tried all the solutions available and still could not resolve these warnings.

If some one has answer for this, I would be really grateful

Thank You in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions)

Comment: Its for linux and also I don't use anaconda. So may be this question should not be duplicate

Comment: are you building from source?

Comment: I have to because I have no other options

Comment: why can't you install via pip?

Comment: I had installed it via pip but the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're building tensorflow from source and your using the highly experimental [bazel for windows](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/windows.html)

You could use the these arguments:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 \
   --copt=-mfma \
   --copt=-mfpmath=both \ 
   --copt=-msse4.2 \
   --config=cuda -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

remove `--config=cuda -k` if you're not building with cuda support.

Comment: I am building it now on my ubuntu machine and the will install the .whl file into windows. I don't know if that will work or not but lets see

Comment: I tried building the file but it failed so can there be a method I can instruct the interpreter to ignore the warnings completely