# How should I execute the Bazel Build Command in compiling Tensorflow?

Tags: python, terminal, tensorflow, cpu, sse

I've been trying to install Tensorflow for a few weeks now and I keep getting a lot of errors with the simple installations so I think that it would be best for me to install Tensorflow from source. I'm following the instructions on the Tensorflow website exactly, and my ./configure is mostly all default so I can see if it works before I make modifications:

`./configure
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] n
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] n
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N] 
No XLA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages]
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] n
No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] n
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
Configuration finished`

(This is not the first time I've edited the configuration)

After this, I execute the following bazel build command straight from the Tensorflow.org website instructions for installing from source :

`bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

(In the future, I'm going to add some additional flags to account for the fact that I've been getting CPU instruction errors about SSE, AVX, etc.)

When I execute that bazel command, I get an extremely long wait time and a list of errors that piles up:

`r08ErCk:tensorflow kendrick$ bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
WARNING: /Users/kendrick/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:exporter': Use SavedModel Builder instead.
WARNING: /Users/kendrick/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:gc': Use SavedModel instead.
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Compiling external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/embed.cc [for host]:
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/embed.cc:37:12: warning: unused variable 'output_file' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const char output_file[] = "well_known_types_embed.cc";
           ^
1 warning generated.
INFO: From Compiling external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/pyext/message_factory.cc:
external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/pyext/message_factory.cc:78:28: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
  static char* kwlist[] = {"pool", 0};
                           ^
external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/pyext/message_factory.cc:222:6: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
    {"pool", (getter)GetPool, NULL, "DescriptorPool"},
     ^
external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/pyext/message_factory.cc:222:37: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
    {"pool", (getter)GetPool, NULL, "DescriptorPool"},
                                    ^
3 warnings generated.`

This is only a small portion of all the errors that looked similar to this that piled up. Even after all of the error messages, the command never returns and I just get the blinking cursor on an empty line.

**Can someone please provide me with some exact instructions on what I should enter into terminal to avoid these errors? I've been following stack advice for weeks but continue to get errors.**

MAC OS Sierra (MacBook Air)

**What should I enter into terminal? (specifically)**

Everything that I've done up to this point has been almost exactly what is told to do on the Tensorflow.org website instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I installed for the first time using http://queirozf.com/entries/installing-cuda-tk-and-tensorflow-on-a-clean-ubuntu-16-04-install and not only was it a very simple process, but working with tf is really easy.. just `source <name_of_virtual_environment>/bin/activate` and then run python/python3 through that.
Bear in mind that the walkthrough in the link is for gpu tensorflow, however using the cpu tensorflow download for your mac instead, with with this virtual environment process should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have a GPU, do have SSE and AVX, and are on a mac sierra - the instructions found on google will NOT work with 1.3. i am befuddled on why they do not provide an exact script to do this. Regardless, here is the answer to your question http://www.josephmiguel.com/building-tensorflow-1-3-from-source-on-mac-osx-sierra-macbook-pro-i7-with-sse-and-avx/

```
/*
do each of these steps independently
will take around 1hr to complete all the steps regardless of machine type

*/


one time install

install anaconda3 pkg # manually download this and install the package
conda update conda
conda create -n dl python=3.6 anaconda
source activate dl

cd /
brew install bazel
pip install six numpy wheel
pip install –upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/protobuf-3.1.0-cp35-none-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl

sudo -i
cd /
rm -rf tensorflow # if rerunning the script
cd /
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow


Step 1

cd /tensorflow
git checkout r1.3 -f
cd /
chmod -R 777 tensorflow
cd /tensorflow
./configure # accept all default settings


Step 2

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions
bazel build –config=opt –copt=-mavx –copt=-mavx2 –copt=-mfma //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package


Step 3

bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl


Step 4

cd ~
ipython


Step 5

import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant(‘Hello, TensorFlow!’)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))


Step 6

pip uninstall /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl
```