# Not able to resolve the warnings being given by tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Whenever I run any script using Tensor Flow, I get the following warnings:

```
The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but 
these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU 
computations
```

I tried to follow the method posted on [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions) and entered the following command on the command line:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

However I get the following error

```
The 'build' command is only supported from within a workspace.
```

How do I solve this error and then make the tensor flow compile using SSE instructions

Answer (score 0):

The [Installing Tensorflow from Sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) page explains the procedure pretty well, make sure you have all the requirements met before running the build step.

If you wish to automate the `./configure` (tensorflow-cpu) step you can run the following command from TF's root directory:

```
# CPU default configuration
tensorflow/tools/ci_build/builds/configured CPU
```

and then run the `build` command with native optimization:

```
# build with native optimization
bazel build -c opt --copt=-march=native tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Comment: I used this https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux and install via pip there

Comment: The compiled binary in the pip package doesn't include device-specific optimizations. To get those you need to compile from source as explained in the link in my answer.

Comment: Would i need to uninstall tensorflow first? If so how?

Comment: You just need to follow the steps and in the last step, just do `pip install -U ...` (note the extra `-U` parameter for update) instead of just `pip install` to uninstall the current version and install the new one.

Comment: When I do ./configure, It asks for a bunch of inputs for which I am not sure what to do? Could you give a more detailed answer please

Comment: The `./configure` command provides defaults that usually don't need to be modified so you can just press enter for all answers. I updated my answer to include a way to automated the configuration step for you.

Comment: rjmessibarca: for configure questions, you can just use defaults for everything. The default option (--config=opt) will enable all optimizations on your system