# When build tensorflow1.2 with mkl-support, got the runtime warning "The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions"

Tags: performance, tensorflow, intel-mkl

1. follow the instruction from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/build-and-install-tensorflow-on-intel-architecture
2. `bazel build --config=mkl --copt="-DEIGEN_USE_VML" -s -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`
3. `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`
4. `pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl`

When I import tensorflow, got the warning

> 2017-08-16 15:30:32.132057: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1108] OpKernel ('op: "Fact" device_type: "CPU" label: "sergey"') for unknown op: Fact
>
> 2017-08-16 15:30:32.132104: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1108] OpKernel ('op: "Fact" device_type: "GPU" host_memory_arg: "fact"') for unknown op: Fact
>
> 2017-08-16 15:30:32.132689: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1108] OpKernel ('op: "Fact" device_type: "CPU" label: "Sergey"') for unknown op: Fact
>   WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py:170: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
>
> 2017-08-16 15:30:32.262141: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>
> 2017-08-16 15:30:32.262189: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>
> 2017-08-16 15:30:32.262203: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>
> 2017-08-16 15:30:32.262222: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>
> 2017-08-16 15:30:32.262239: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

Does anyone get the similar warning? and how to fix it. BTW, i use anaconda (conda 4.0.5) to install the tensorflow package.

Comment: Take a look at this question and the first answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions), you might need to add the flags `--copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2` to your bazel build command

Comment: Actually, thanks for your comment, problem resolved.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! You might want to add and accept your own answer detailing which options you used in the build to make it work, it sounds like a problem other people might run into

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions)

Comment: `-mavx2` doesn't enable FMA.  You should use `--copt=-march=native`.