# illegal instruction error when building Tensorflow from source

Tags: python, gcc, tensorflow

I'm building tensorflow from source with bazel, as described here:
`https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources`

Following the installation doc, I successfully compile with the following:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both \
--cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"--config=cuda \
-k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

a combination of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions) and a note in the installation documentation "to add `--cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"` to the build command for gcc 5 and later".

however, `import tensorflow as tf` results in the error

```
illegal instruction (core dumped), exiting python.
```

I have additionally tried: `conda update libgcc` to no avail.

How can I build tensorflow from source with gcc 5.0?

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but just to be sure: your CPU has support for all the build flags you're specifying, right?

Comment: I did not examine the flags closely - but think it would fail to compile if they weren't supported.

Comment: No, it will compile just fine and produce a binary for a different processor. Run in your bash `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target | grep enabled ` and double check that al the flags you specify are actually in the list (especially the -mavx2 and -mfma)

Comment: Woops, I forgot that -mfpmath doesn't show as enabled or disabled. Have a look at the full output of the gcc command for the possible values you can specify (although `both` should be fine)

Comment: @GPhilo looks like I should have checked more closely!

Comment: I'll just recap in an answer then, since it's the kind of problem other people might run into ;)

Comment: @GPhilo, may  I know how can I check whether my CPU has support for all the build flags. I use linux aarch64 and I install tensorflow from ```conda install tensorflow```. Installation does not give any issue. But when I predict the model , it gives ```Illegal instruction (core dump)```. My tensorflow version is 2.5.0 and numpy is 1.20.3. Should I install tensorflow from bazel?

Comment: @anon01, do you have any document of how to build tensorflow from bazel source file?

Comment: @Susan the only info I have is in the link at the top: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

Comment: @anon01, what linux architecture are you using?

Comment: I mean, the question was from five years ago. I don't remember asking it tbh :)

Comment: @Susan try installing via pip instead of conda. IIRC at a certain point Tensorflow started building with advanced CPU instructions enabled by default, but I can't remember when that was, check the release info on GitHub for each version of TF 2.x, it should be in there somewhere. If that's the case, your only option is building from source (in which case, there's instructions for it on Tensorflow's website)

Comment: @GPhilo, I read TF 2.5.0's git in this website https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases?page=4 ```oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) CPU performance optimizations from Intel-optimized TensorFlow are now available in the official x86-64 Linux and Windows builds.
They are off by default. Enable them by setting the environment variable TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=1.``` Does it mean Tensorflow 2.5.0 is available for only x86-64 architecture?

Comment: @GPhilo, But at the end of TF2.5.0, it mentions ```Other

Added show_debug_info to mlir.convert_graph_def and mlir.convert_function.
Added Arm Compute Library (ACL) support to --config=mkl_aarch64 build.``` under Bug Fixes and Other Changes.  and the support link is https://github.com/ARM-software/ComputeLibrary. May I know is TF 2.5.0 support aarch64 architecture or not? Should I need to install tensorflow from the bazel?

Comment: _Does it mean Tensorflow 2.5.0 is available for only x86-64 architecture?_ No, it means there are some specific optimizations enabled if your CPU supports them. _May I know is TF 2.5.0 support aarch64 architecture or not?_ It does, but depending on what you're trying to install TF on, you might have to build from source (which is most likely done via `bazel`). What machine are you trying to install TF on?

Comment: @GPhilo, I am using aarch64 architecture. I also searched how to install tensorflow with bazel. http://zhiyisun.github.io/2017/02/15/Running-Google-Machine-Learning-Library-Tensorflow-On-ARM-64-bit-Platform.html I follow according to this. But in the website it said ```Then modify bazel source file to compatible with aarch64.``` I don't know how to modify the bazel source with the code mentioned below in the website.  So I skip that step and try to compile ./compile.sh. But I got ```ERROR: JAVA_HOME (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java) is not a path to a working JDK.```

Comment: ``` ls -l /etc/alternatives/java``` gives ```/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java```.

```java --version ``` ```openjdk 11.0.16 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode)```.  ```echo $JAVA_HOME``` gives
```/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java```

Comment: May I know how can I solve Error: Java_home is not a path to a working JDK?

Comment: @susan building on aarch64 is not trivial (and out of scope for this question). Check out [this guide](https://qengineering.eu/install-tensorflow-2.4.0-on-jetson-nano.html) that shows how to build TF on a Jetson Nano (in thelinks at the bottom of the page you also have other options like Raspberry Pi). The java error is probably a configuration issue: if you don't need java bindings, you probably need to disable the build for them. If you do, I can't help as I never had to build them and have no clue of how that's done.

Comment: @GPhilo, When I install Tensorflow from bazel, Bazel is written in Java according to the guide you shared and to compile Bazel, we must first install Java.

Comment: @susan look up bazelisk and see if that applies to your use-case, it should take care of setting up the correct bazel version for the project you're building.

Comment: @GPhilo, Thank you for the guide. May  I know is bazelisk alternative of bazel? But I can solved the issue of ```Error: Java_home is not a path to a working JDK``` and now I can compile Bazel by following the steps from the guide that you shared.

Comment: @GPhilo, In the guide, after compiling the bazel, I need to copy the binary bazel file from ```output/bazel``` to ```/usr/local/bin/bazel```. May I know when I use the virtual environment using miniconda3 instead of virtual environment from the local, where should I copy the ```output/bazel```? When I check the miniconda3 folder, I found the following subfolders. ```LICENSE.txt                   compiler_compat  etc      python-package
aarch64-conda-linux-gnu       conda-meta       include  share
aarch64-conda_cos7-linux-gnu  condabin         lib      shell
bin     envs    pkgs     ssl
```

Comment: Hello, anon01, how do you know what command you should run to build the Tensorflow using bazel ```-c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both \
--cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"--config=cuda \
-k ``` Because, I want to build Tensorflow for cpu version in aarch64 linux architecture and I don't know what comment I should use to build Tensorflow with bazel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message tells me your program was compiled with instructions your processor doesn't have and a look at your build string makes me suspect of `-mavx2` and `-mfma` which AFAIK are implemented only in rather recent (and high-end) CPUs.
Please note, **gcc will compile just fine with flags for instructions your CPU doesn't support, but the program won't run on your machine**.

To make sure your CPU supports those flags, run in bash `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target | grep enabled` and check that the output contains all the build flags you want to use (with the exception of `-mfpmath` which doesn't show as enabled or disabled since it allows a list of output. For that you'll need to check the full `gcc -march=...` command output).

To answer to your final comment, there is no way to "enable" these instructions, they are implemented in hardware and either they are available on your CPU, or they aren't.

Comment: noobish question - is it possible to compile tensorflow with these features turned off, for sake of development on old CPUs?

Comment: Of course! In the `configure` script there's a stage that asks you what compiler optimization flags to pass, specifying that native is the default. Just replace that with an empty string and that should do it. Otherwise, I think not adding the `-c=opt` option to your Bazel build command should also be equivalent (since those compiler flags are applied when you add that flag to the build command)