# Tensorflow: Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I work under Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a Virtual Machine. Recently, I used `pip3 install tensorflow` to install TensorFlow.  I got the following error:

```
$ python3

Python 3.8.17 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jun 16 2023, 07:06:00) 

[GCC 11.4.0] on linux

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tensorflow as tf

Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I have tried a lot of solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092527/illegal-instructioncore-dumped-tensorflow) but all in vain.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you may have an old anaconda installation, so try and update it:

- `conda update --all`

If possible download install latest anaconda that uses 3.10.3

Then install tensorflow:

- `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

I recommend creating a virtual environment after update:

- `conda create -n <myenvname> -c conda-forge python=3.8.17 tensorflow`