# TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2, FMA in pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using pycharm to code and I successfully download tensorflow. But it gives me the warnings as:

```
The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but 
these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU 
computations.
The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but 
these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU 
computations.
The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but 
these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU 
computations.
The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but 
these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU 
computations.
```

I saw other links and it doesn't solve my question. I tried to install tensorflow again by Source. And I stuck with building the pip package:

```
$ bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

And my computer gives me the error:

```
ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
```

I use mac and I don't familiar with Cpp so don't understand what it means.
Anybody can help me solve this question?

Comment: That message is a warning, not an error....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions)

Answer (score 1):

These warnings do not matter, but you can compile Tensorflow by `bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-msse4.2 //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` to disable them.

Comment: Yes when I build pip package like that. It will throw the error:
ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]