# TensorFlow: bazel error when building pip package

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

Was following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions) to compile TensorFlow library.

Using this code `bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`, however, got the following error.

```
WARNING: Config values are not defined in any .rc file: cuda
ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': no such package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': BUILD file not found on package path
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
INFO: Analysed 0 targets (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 0 targets...
ERROR: command succeeded, but there were errors parsing the target pattern
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.331s, Critical Path: 0.02s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Is this because I installed TensorFlow using pip?

Any sugguest what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `./configure`. That will create a `.bazelrc` and `.tf_configure.bazel` file in your Tensorflow workspace.

The `--config=cuda` Bazel flag refers to entries in those two files (they are both text files). The entries typically look like this: `build:cuda --some_bazel_flag`.