# error bazel build in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, build, bazel

At first, I would like to use bazel to help me run tensorflow with SSE and avx so I tried this within work space:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

but it gives me a new error like following, I wonder what is wrong and what should I do? Thanks for help.

> WARNING: Config values are not defined in any .rc file: cuda
>   ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': no such package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': BUILD file not found on package path
>   WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
>   INFO: Analysed 0 targets (2 packages loaded).
>   INFO: Found 0 targets...
>   ERROR: command succeeded, but there were errors parsing the target pattern
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 2.727s, Critical Path: 0.02s
>   FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an outdated bazel. I am not sure but you can try to use `--config=opt` instead of `-c opt` for initial versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `./configure`. That will create a `.bazelrc` and `.tf_configure.bazel` file in your Tensorflow workspace.

The `--config=cuda` Bazel flag refers to entries in those two files (they are both text files). The entries typically look like this: `build:cuda --some_bazel_flag.`

It was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46868993/tensorflow-bazel-error-when-building-pip-package)