# How to speed up my CPU computation with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow-serving

I just started coding in tensorflow with anaconda environment and I'm working on my Windows10 laptop with Intel integrated graphics only. I tried some of the basic programs using CPU it showing me something like below. But I can't get it, how to make use of it?

```
2017-11-23 11:37:51.842265: W c:\l\tensorflow_1501907206084\work\tensorflow-1.2.1\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-23 11:37:51.860180: W c:\l\tensorflow_1501907206084\work\tensorflow-1.2.1\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-23 11:37:51.860442: W c:\l\tensorflow_1501907206084\work\tensorflow-1.2.1\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-23 11:37:51.860697: W c:\l\tensorflow_1501907206084\work\tensorflow-1.2.1\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-23 11:37:51.860951: W c:\l\tensorflow_1501907206084\work\tensorflow-1.2.1\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-23 11:37:51.861207: W c:\l\tensorflow_1501907206084\work\tensorflow-1.2.1\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-23 11:37:51.861459: W c:\l\tensorflow_1501907206084\work\tensorflow-1.2.1\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-23 11:37:51.861718: W c:\l\tensorflow_1501907206084\work\tensorflow-1.2.1\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

Comment: You need to build from source on your machine. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions

Comment: Thanks for the help!!..@Vj- ..I'll surely check it.