# my first deep network

Tags: python, matplotlib, neural-network, keras, sklearn-pandas

this is my first deep neural network and I have a problem in this code
while implementing it.
beside the error the code is slow and it is another thing.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


x, y = make_moons(n_samples=1000, noise=0.1, random_state=0)
plt.plot(x[y == 0, 0], x[y == 0, 1], 'ob', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(x[y == 1, 0], x[y == 1, 1], 'xr', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(['0', '1'])
plt.show()
print(x.shape)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.3, random_state=42)
model = Sequential
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.5), 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=200, verbose=0)
results = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('The Accuracy score on the Train set is:\t{:0.3f}'.format(results[1]))
```

Here is the error

```
> Using TensorFlow backend. 2017-11-24 17:03:32.402292: W
> C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but
> these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
> computations. 2017-11-24 17:03:32.402768: W
> C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but
> these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
> computations. (1000, 2) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "E:/Tutorial/Deep Learning.py", line 18, in <module>
>     model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid')) TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'layer'
```

Comment: Well with matplotlib, you need to do `plt.show()` to start the event loop that shows the plot.  But it seems you also have some other errors.

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is. What part of it is unexpected?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear what the problem is. Did you try solving it?

Comment: i did look for it in the documentation but there is nothing

Comment: You need a `Sequential` instance. You've not instantiated it with `Sequential()`

Comment: my keras version is 2.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parentheses after `Sequential`:

```
model = Sequential()
```

If you want to compile tensorflow to make use of special x86 instructions such as AVX then see [How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions) but this might be more effort than it is worth.