# Recompile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow

I'm following along with the pyimagesearch book, which comes with an ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine that already has all the libraries (sklearn, keras, etc.) installed and everything setup. When I first ran some of the code with keras, however, I got the warning `The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computation`, and the same for `AVX`. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions) as well as [installing from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), but both seem to assume that TensorFlow hasn't been installed yet, which it already has. Do I just have to uninstall and start over? Or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning, it won't stop you from using TensorFlow. But if you would like TensorFlow to use these instructions, you'll need to re-install it. [TensorFlow 1.6+ pip packages are compiled with AVX by default](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md#breaking-changes), but for other instructions you'd need to compile TensorFlow from source.