# How to compile tensorflow static lib with cpu sse support?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, sse

Briefly speaking, I need to build tensorflow into a static lib, and I have successfully achieved that goal by scripts under tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_linux.sh. 
But after linking this libtensorflow-core.a to my test program, it showed that the performance is surprisingly poor. I found a bunch of logs like below exists. It seems no cpu sse support has been built into the static lib.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
2018-05-04 13:45:44.304314: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1242] OpKernel ('op: "EncodeProto" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: EncodeProto
2018-05-04 13:45:44.304648: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1242] OpKernel ('op: "DecodeProtoV2" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: DecodeProtoV2
2018-05-04 13:45:44.304720: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1242] OpKernel ('op: "PopulationCount" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT64 } } }') for unknown op: PopulationCount 
2018-05-04 13:45:44.304732: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1242] OpKernel ('op: "PopulationCount" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } }') for unknown op: PopulationCount 
2018-05-04 13:45:44.304741: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1242] OpKernel ('op: "PopulationCount" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT16 } } }') for unknown op: PopulationCount 
2018-05-04 13:45:44.304750: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1242] OpKernel ('op: "PopulationCount" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_UINT16 } } }') for unknown op: PopulationCount 
2018-05-04 13:45:44.304759: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1242] OpKernel ('op: "PopulationCount" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT8 } } }') for unknown op: PopulationCount 
2018-05-04 13:45:44.304768: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1242] OpKernel ('op: "PopulationCount" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_UINT8 } } }') for unknown op: PopulationCount 
2018-05-04 13:45:44.304910: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1242] OpKernel ('op: "MutableDenseHashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT64 } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_VARIANT } } }') for unknown op: MutableDenseHashTable
```

Comment: What compiler did you use?  `gcc -O3 -march=native` should be good.  Possible duplicate of [How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41293077)