# TensorFlow HelloWorld wrong with rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags

Tags: python, tensorflow

## source code

```py
import tensorflow as tf
constant_a = tf.constant('Hello World!')
with tf.Session() as session:
  print(session.run(constant_a))
```

## problem log

```
2022-04-14 16:26:07.486097: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....source_code_path/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    with tf.Session() as session:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

## enviroment

running in virtualenv.

python: 3.9.7

tensorflow: 2.8.0

SOS.(TAT)

Comment: Your code is supposed to run on TF v1.x. Downgrade your TensorFlow version, or update your code to be compliant with TF v2.8

Comment: @Lescurel THX. Too much old tutorials...

Answer (score 1):

In tensorflow v2.x, you can print this "Hello World!" with:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
constant_a = tf.constant('Hello World!')
print(constant_a)
```

You will get
`tf.Tensor(b'Hello World!', shape=(), dtype=string)` in your shell.

About this problem:

```
This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

It doesn't seem to make any difference in this program. So use this can ignore the warning:

```py
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

But, if you want to solve this question, maybe [build from source](https://tensorflow.google.cn/install/source) will help. I'll just sit on this shit, because I use tf just for a short period homework... :P

Looking forward to someone answer this question again, with this warning solved.

And, [how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions).